# Problems with finding out file path via descriptor

Tags: c, linux, path, ptrace, readlink

The challenge is to fish out the "write" and find out where and how many bytes were written. I use "ptrace" to catch it, but I have problems with further path detection. I use "readlink" to get the path descriptor. But it returns strings like "pipe:[766279]". What could be the problem? How to find out the full path to the file in this case?

```
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/ptrace.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <linux/limits.h>
    #include <sys/user.h>
    
    typedef struct Counter {
        char filename[PATH_MAX];
        int counter;
        struct Counter* next;
    } Counter;
    
    typedef struct Counters {
        struct Counter* head;
    } Counters;
    
    void increment(Counters* counters, const char* filename, int value) {
        Counter* current = counters->head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(current->filename, filename) == 0) {
                current->counter += value;
                return;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
    
        Counter* new_entry = malloc(sizeof(Counter));
        new_entry->next = counters->head;
        new_entry->counter = value;
        strncpy(new_entry->filename, filename, PATH_MAX - 1);
        new_entry->filename[PATH_MAX - 1] = '\0';
        counters->head = new_entry;
    }
    
    void print(Counters* counters) {
        Counter* current = counters->head;
        while (current != NULL) {
            printf("%s:%d\n", current->filename, current->counter);
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    
    void get_file_path(int fd, char* path, size_t path_size) {
        char fd_path[PATH_MAX];
        snprintf(fd_path, sizeof(fd_path), "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd);
        int size = readlink(fd_path, path, path_size - 1);
        if (size < 0) {
            perror("readlink");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        path[size] = '\0';
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        Counters counters;
        counters.head = NULL;
    
        pid_t child_pid = fork();
    
        if (child_pid == -1) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (child_pid == 0) {
            ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
            execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
            perror("execvp");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {
            int status;
            waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
    
            while (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
                ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child_pid, NULL, NULL);
                waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
                struct user_regs_struct regs;
                ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, child_pid, NULL, &regs);
                if (regs.orig_rax == 1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "we search %lld\n", regs.rdi);
                    char filename[PATH_MAX];
                    long int addr = regs.rdi;
                    char data[PATH_MAX];
                    get_file_path(regs.rdi, data, PATH_MAX);
                    data[PATH_MAX - 1] = '\0';
                    increment(&counters, filename, regs.rdx);
                }
            }
            print(&counters);
            Counter* current = counters.head;
            while (current != NULL) {
                Counter* next = current->next;
                free(current);
                current = next;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I read that this can happen if it is a pipe-channel or an irregular file. But in the testing system they use a Python script, where writing to files of extension ".txt" goes through "echo" and everything should be OK. I'm sure I'm catching the right "write" system call, because the number of bytes written is the same. In the tests, a temporary directory is created in a loop and the command that writes looks like this "echo -n aaaaaaaaa 1>/tmp/tmp2baliyc8/uhjpiewboo". Realised that I get a file descriptor on "FIFO/pipe". And in response I want a string like '/tmp/tmp2baliyc8/uhjpiewboo'. But I still haven't figured out how to get it

Comment: `/self/fd` looks wrong. That will look at the parent process' file descriptors. You probably want to put the child pid instead of `self` in there. Also, please add the missing header files and make it into a [mre]. What is `Counters` for example?

Comment: File descriptors aren't necessarily for *files*; other things like pipes and sockets use them too. And thanks to hard links even files can have multiple entries in a file system for the same entity. Trying to get a canonical path from one is often impossible.

Comment: @TamerisIsamidinova Please don't put loose hints in the comments. Update your question so that we can compile the program. That is, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Shawn That is, having in rdi: The file descriptor where the write occurs, in rsi: A pointer to the buffer from which the write occurs, in rdx: The number of bytes to be written.

I won't be able to know which file the write occurred to?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Sorry, I put all the code in the question)

Comment: @TamerisIsamidinova Ok, it was as I suspected and I posted my suggested change as an answer.

Comment: @TamerisIsamidinova It looks like you accidentally removed the code from the question so I put it back. Without it, this Q&A will not be of much help to others coming here with a similar problem.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I deleted the code for a while as there was an anti-plagiarism check. But thanks for bringing it back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the links in `/proc/self/fd`, you will read what the parent process is opening. Since you want to trace the child, you should replace `self` with the process id of the child.

Example:

```c
void get_file_path(int fd, pid_t pid, char* path, size_t path_size) {
    char fd_path[PATH_MAX];
    snprintf(fd_path, sizeof(fd_path), "/proc/%d/fd/%d", (int)pid, fd);
    ssize_t size = readlink(fd_path, path, path_size - 1);
    if(size < 0) {
        perror("readlink");
        path[0] = '\0';
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    path[size] = '\0';
    fprintf(stderr, "WE GOT [%s]\n", path); // debug print to see that it works
}
```

The call to the function in the parent process would then need to be:

```c
get_file_path(regs.rdi, child_pid, data, PATH_MAX);
//                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

You can now see the program correctly printing out the name of the file the child process opened in the `WE GOT [...]` debug printout.

This does not fix everything else in the program, like `char filename[PATH_MAX];` being uninitialized and never changed, but used in comparisons in `increment` - or the fact that you populate `data` in the `get_file_path` call, but never use it.